# HTML5 Canvas with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, canvas

I would like to try a website that will represented as a graph related to prices changes .  It will be based on wordpress . in other words ,  i will keep prices list in wordpress post meta and  i would like to show in frontend as a graph .

I wanna know is should i use HTML5 canvas for showing graph ??? . 
Is that reliable enough to use ?? 
and also about learning curve since i am totally new about graphical data ???. 
If HTML isn't reliable enough ,  is there any other ways to use it ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both canvas and SVG work just fine with any wordpress install.

If you don't know anything about the technologies, a library is probably your best bet for getting started.

[Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) for instance, the SVG library, makes creating some graphs very easy. Look at their demos.